# HTML table dropdown value for each row

Tags: javascript, html

when i select from dropdown it will only change the first row.

i want to get different value for each row. what do i do wrong? how to fix it?

[image]

my html code:

```
                {% for tr in db_training %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="tweet">{{tr.tweets}}</td>
                    <td class="type">{{tr.dtype}}</td>
                    <td class="manual">
                        <select id="dselect" onchange="getValue(this)">
                            <option value="$">Pilih</option>
                            <option value="negatif">Negatif</option>
                            <option value="netral">Netral</option>
                            <option value="positif">Positif</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td id="dselect-value"></td>
                    <td class="auto">{{tr.auto}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

...

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function getValue(data) {
                var myDiv = document.getElementById(data.id + '-value');
                myDiv.innerHTML = data.value;
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: Your resulting html has elements with same id multiple times. Try to add row index to ids. Good luck!

Comment: hey, added an answer for you

Comment: thank you so much for your help. really appreciate it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use different id's for select and target

Django template variable `forloop.counter` starting from index 1

If you need start index `0` then use `forloop.counter0`

```
{% for tr in db_training %}
    <tr>
        <td class="tweet">{{tr.tweets}}</td>
        <td class="type">{{tr.dtype}}</td>
        <td class="manual">
            <select id="dselect_{{ forloop.counter }}" onchange="getValue(this)">
                <option value="$">Pilih</option>
                <option value="negatif">Negatif</option>
                <option value="netral">Netral</option>
                <option value="positif">Positif</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td id="dselect_{{ forloop.counter }}-value"></td>
        <td class="auto">{{tr.auto}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the same id for all rows. try to go after target instead.
This should help you instead

```
        function getValue(data) {
            var myDiv =data.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("#dselect-value");
            myDiv.innerHTML = data.value;
        }
```